# Setting system wide proxy through bash script (Temporarily)

Tags: bash, proxy

I'm trying to temporarily set the system wide proxy option which is available as GUI in the Network Settings through bash script. I only want the proxy to be applicable while the script is running and has to reset to no proxy when the script ends. So, basically, I am looking for something like:

> ----Script Start----
>
> Change Proxy to a predefined IP, port combination
>
> Run
>
> On close, reset proxy
>
> ----Script End-----

Now, I saw something on setting the environment variable but I am not sure how to apply this temporarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type the following command to set proxy server in linux command line.

`export http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128/`

Put a back tick character (`) before and after that command so that bash will execute the EXPORT command.

Note: 1.2.3.4 is your proxy server ip address and 3128 is the port for example.

To remove the variable value, use this command.

`unset VARIABLE_NAME`

Exmaple:

`unset http_proxy`

Comment: This is not where the proxy info I gave at install time went.. :\