# Setting proxy in apt.conf using Bash Script

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts, proxy

I wrote the following bash script to write the proxy in the apt.conf file, and hide it from being echoed to the terminal.

```
sudo echo "Acquire::http::proxy  "http://"$prox":"$port"/";" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf > /dev/null 2>&1
sudo echo "Acquire::https::proxy  "https://"$prox":"$port"/";" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf > /dev/null 2>&1
sudo echo "Acquire::ftp::proxy  "ftp://"$prox":"$port"/";" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Although the commands write to the apt.conf file, but on running the script, I get the following error :

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:6: Extra junk at end of file
```

Help appreciated over this!

Comment: Why do you believe that `echo` benefits from super-user privileges? It doesn't use any system resources beyond the already open standard output file descriptor. No need for privileges to acquire additional resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ravexina's answer identifies the underlying reason correctly:

> You need to quote the config value.

However, if you find escaped quotation marks difficult to read or simply ugly there's an alternative:

```
printf 'Acquire::http::proxy "http://%s:%u";\n' "$prox" "$port" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf > /dev/null
```

I think you can do the other two lines on your own.

#### Improvements suggestions:

There's a lot of repetition in your code which you could avoid with a loop:

```
for proto in http https ftp; do
    printf 'Acquire::%s::proxy "%s://%s:%u";\n' "$proto" "$proto" "$prox" "$port"
done |
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks David! I'm new to bash scripting and still exploring it :) 
Needed another help, if you could : I want to set network proxy for gnome and kde, just similar to the manual way of :  System Settings->Proxy->Set Manual Proxy and Enter respective port and proxies. Is it possible to do that via bash scripting?

Comment: @HritikGupta: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Please help me here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/931662/setting-proxy-using-bash-script Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the config value:

```
"Acquire::http::proxy  \""http://"$prox":"$port""\";"
```

If you try to echo it out:

```
echo "Acquire::http::proxy  \""http://"$prox":"$port""\";"
```

output should be like:

```
Acquire::http::proxy  "http://x.x.x.x:yy";
```

And not:

```
Acquire::http::proxy  http://x.x.x.x:yy/;
```

Because `http://x.x.x.x:yy/` is a junk in eye of `apt`.

Also you don't need `sudo` before `echo` as David mentioned ;)

Comment: Thank you Ravexina! I'm new to bash scripting and still exploring it :) Needed another help, if you could : I want to set network proxy for gnome and kde, just similar to the manual way of : System Settings->Proxy->Set Manual Proxy and Enter respective port and proxies. Is it possible to do that via bash scripting?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/350460/#350483

Comment: Hasn't it got to do anything with config files like gsettings or kde.config? Also I doubt if export sets network proxy, as I still have to manually enter proxies in that dialog box after executing this command.

Comment: I'm not a GUI person don't know really about these, however the link I provided will enable the proxy in your terminal window.

Comment: The same command doesn't work for **fish shell**. I have to type : set -Ux http_proxy "http://"$prox":"$port"". But, when I execute this by my script, it shows the error : `prox.sh: 61: set: Illegal option -U`

Comment: @HritikGupta: If your question is about [tag:fish] please clarify that and replace its [tag:bash] tag. However, if you have a *new* question about an equivalent *fish* script, please open a [new question](/questions/ask). The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.